# MySQL : Count Id by dates in several columns with date_format group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below table `Delivery` in MySQL:

```
id      idate               Client  Groupe  Des     Open_Date           Status  Update_Date         Install_Date
316161  05/03/2022 11:17    a       z       e       05/02/2022 18:04    aa      18/08/2022 18:40    NULL
316160  18/08/2022 16:19    b       y       f       17/08/2022 08:13    bb      NULL                30/09/2022 12:49
316159  25/09/2022 21:47    c       x       g       30/08/2022 23:56    aa      05/10/2022 09:24    06/10/2022 20:37
316158  02/10/2022 01:34    d       w       h       02/10/2022 00:04    dd      NULL                NULL
```

I would like to count the number of ID for each '%Y-%m' to have an output like:

```
date        idate_count     opdate_count    update_count    instdate_count
NULL        0               0               2               2
2022-02     0               1               0               0
2022-03     1               0               0               0
2022-08     1               2               1               0
2022-09     1               0               0               1
2022-10     1               1               1               1
```

For the moment I'm only able to count the ID for only one date column with this code

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(idate, '%Y-%m') AS date, COUNT(id) AS idate_count
FROM Delivery
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(idate, '%Y-%m');
```

Any guidance would be appreciated! Thx!

---

**edit**

In this case, counting NULL in my dates is important. It will be helpful to monitor ID no updated or not installed.
Also, we have some error with Opendate as NULL, so is a good indicator to track and count how many ID affected.

Comment: If your MySQL is version 8 (or higher) you can use windows functions for aggregation,  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: Unfortunately my version is lower :(

Comment: Is that first NULL row in the desired output helpful in this case?

Comment: Yes I would like to count the NULL in case an ID a task is not assigned yet or there is a mistake because in my base for idate and opendate I have some NULL and I shouldn't. So counting the dates NULL is also helpful to track errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand how to read the first row of your desired output, in which you are listing a NULL date and some metrics for that row. Are you trying to say that two records were Updated without a date?

Here's a solution that works for MySQL 5.*, where we are using a cartesian join to all the possible dates that you may have. Then using conditional aggregation for your counts. Note: I'm not counting the NULL dates as I don't see how that's helpful.

---

```
select t.yyyy_mm, 
  sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(idate, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm then 1 else 0 end) as idate_count, 
  sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm then 1 else 0 end) as opdate_count, 
  sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(update_date, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm then 1 else 0 end) as update_count, 
  sum(case when DATE_FORMAT(install_date, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm then 1 else 0 end) as instdate_count
 from delivery as d, 
  (
   select DATE_FORMAT(idate, '%Y-%m') as yyyy_mm from delivery union
   select DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m') from delivery union
   select DATE_FORMAT(update_date, '%Y-%m') from delivery union
   select DATE_FORMAT(install_date, '%Y-%m') from delivery
  ) as t
 where t.yyyy_mm is not null
 group by t.yyyy_mm;
```

| yyyy_mm | idate_count | opdate_count | update_count | instdate_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-08 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-09 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wH3m2LnhLc36nSEuDRMTua/1)

---

**UPDATE**

Slightly shorter version, where we don't need case expressions....

```
 select t.yyyy_mm, 
  sum(DATE_FORMAT(idate, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm) as idate_count, 
  sum(DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm) as opdate_count, 
  sum(DATE_FORMAT(update_date, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm) as update_count, 
  sum(DATE_FORMAT(install_date, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm) as instdate_count
 from delivery as d, 
  (
   select DATE_FORMAT(idate, '%Y-%m') as yyyy_mm from delivery union
   select DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m') from delivery union
   select DATE_FORMAT(update_date, '%Y-%m') from delivery union
   select DATE_FORMAT(install_date, '%Y-%m') from delivery
  ) as t
 where t.yyyy_mm is not null
 group by t.yyyy_mm;
```

Comment: I don't think the case to coerce this into 1 or 0 is necessary.  `sum(DATE_FORMAT(xxxx, '%Y-%m') = t.yyyy_mm)` should suffice, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland Yes, you are correct. Updating the answer. I was thinking too much about the NULL row and went a bit too far.

Comment: @Isolated Thanks a lot for this answer and update ! It helps me a lot. Like I said in my comment above, count the NULL is important to know if the date is properly filled